# Querying Extended Events in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, extended-events

I have created the following event session using a script I got from Kimberly Tripp's SQL Server 2008 Internals book.  It has been modified to send to a file instead of the ring buffer.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION
[statement_completed_file]
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT
    sqlserver.sp_statement_completed,
ADD EVENT
    sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
    (
        ACTION 
        (
            sqlserver.sql_text
        )
        WHERE
        (
            sqlserver.session_id=53
        )
    )
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
    (
        set filename=N'C:\MSSQL\TEMP\stats.xel', 
        metadatafile=N'C:\MSSQL\TEMP\stats.xem'
    )
WITH
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=OFF
)
```

Here is the original script to query the data.

```
SELECT
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS source_database_id,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[2]', 'bigint') AS object_id,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[3]', 'bigint') AS object_type,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[4]', 'bigint') AS cpu,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[5]', 'bigint') AS duration,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[6]', 'bigint') AS reads,
theNodes.event_data.value('(data/value)[7]', 'bigint') AS writes,
theNodes.event_data.value('(action/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS sql_text
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML, st.target_data) AS ring_buffer
        FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets st ON s.address = st.event_session_address
        WHERE s.name = 'statement_completed'
) AS theData
CROSS APPLY
theData.ring_buffer.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') theNodes (event_data)
WHERE theNodes.event_data.value('(action/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') is not null
```

How could I modify it to read from the two files xel and xem instead of the ring buffer.  I have been googling around but the learning curve has been rough.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I suggest downloading [this addin](http://extendedeventmanager.codeplex.com/). Makes playing with XEvents much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to play with this example:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION
[statement_completed_file]
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT
    sqlserver.sp_statement_completed,
ADD EVENT
    sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
    (
        ACTION 
        (
            sqlserver.sql_text
        )
        WHERE
        (
            sqlserver.session_id <> 53
        )
    )
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
    (
        set filename=N'C:\stats.xel', 
        metadatafile=N'C:\stats.xem'
    )
WITH
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=OFF
)
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION [statement_completed_file]
ON SERVER
STATE=START
GO
SELECT event_data, 
    event_data.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS event_name,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS source_database_id,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[2]', 'bigint') AS object_id,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[3]', 'bigint') AS object_type,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[4]', 'bigint') AS cpu,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[5]', 'bigint') AS duration,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[6]', 'bigint') AS reads,
    event_data.value('(event/data/value)[7]', 'bigint') AS writes,
    event_data.value('(event/action/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS sql_text
FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data
    FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\stats*.xel', 'C:\stats*.xem', null, null)
) tbl
GO
DROP EVENT SESSION [statement_completed_file] ON SERVER
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I was hoping actually to figure out a way to just change the cross apply so that it used sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file instead of the ring_buffer.

Comment: You need no any cross apply then, updating an answer

Comment: With your example, I can only access the name of the event session but not the data values underneath.  If I just run the subquery on the file, I see this : <event name="sp_statement_completed" package="sqlserver" id="62" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-29T13:28:56.789Z"><data name="source_database_id"><value>1</value><text />... but I can't seem to access the values

Comment: Added the complete script

Answer (score 2):

Heres another query

```
declare
    xmlData xml;

select
    @xmlData    =   [xet].[event_data]
from
    [sys].fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\stats*.xel', 'C:\stats*.xem', null, null) as [xet];

with cte_xmlData as (
    select
        [e].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as [EventName],
        [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as [EventTimeStamp],
        [d].value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [DdlPhase],
        [d].value('text[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [DdlPhaseDesc],
        [c].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Name],
        [c].value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Value]
    from
        @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event') as [xml]([e])
        inner join @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event/action') as [xml2]([c])
            on ( [c].value('../@timestamp', 'datetime') =  [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') )
        inner join @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event/data') as [xml3]([d])
            on ( [d].value('../@timestamp', 'datetime') =  [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') )
            and ( [d].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'ddl_phase' )
    union
    select
        [e].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as [EventName],
        [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as [EventTimeStamp],
        [d].value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [DdlPhase],
        [d].value('text[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [DdlPhaseDesc],
        [c].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as [Name],
        case
            when [c].exist('text[1]') = 0 then [c].value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
            else [c].value('text[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        end as [Value]
    from
        @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event') as [xml]([e])
        inner join @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event/data') as [xml2]([c])
            on ( [c].value('../@timestamp', 'datetime') =  [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') )
        inner join @xmlData.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event/data') as [xml3]([d])
            on ( [d].value('../@timestamp', 'datetime') =  [e].value('@timestamp', 'datetime') )
            and ( [d].value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'ddl_phase' )
)
/**/
select
    [pData].[EventName],
    [pData].[EventTimeStamp],
    [pData].[DdlPhaseDesc],
    [pData].[event_name],
    [pData].[source_database_id],
    [pData].[object_id],
    [pData].[object_type],
    [pData].[cpu],
    [pData].[duration],
    [pData].[reads],
    [pData].[writes],
    [pData].[sql_text]
from
    [cte_xmlData]
    -- Modify the in statement depending on what you want
    pivot(max([value]) for [name] in ([event_name], [source_database_id], [object_id], [object_type], [cpu], [duration], [reads], [writes], [sql_text])) as [pData]
order by
    [EventTimeStamp],
    [DdlPhase];
```